# SVN pattern for turning a custom application into a product

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, svn

I'm working on taking an application developed for a specific client and turning it into a "foundation" to be used for other future projects; into something of a stand-alone "product".

My question is, is there a recommended approach Subversion approach to doing this?  I'm planning on just creating a "branch" to avoid interfering with the original project (which may or may not be ongoing) but I have a feeling the proper way to do this is to create a branch for the original project and then continue the "productization" in the trunk.

I imagine I'm not the first person to do this, and if there is an established pattern for this process then it will be easier to sell it to the others affected if I need to change their workflow.  If not I'm probably going to have to go with my original plan of branching and building on the branch as to avoid interfering with the original effort.

Thoughts or opinions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a tag for the revision number that represents the "client version" of the code. Then, create a branch of the code from that revision. This will become your client support branch, to which you can implement any bug fixes they report - and reintegrate back into your dev version, which will of course be the trunk. This way, your trunk is always up-to-date with the latest revision of the code.

I've seen other ways of doing this, such as branching for a dev version too, but in my opinion the suggestion above is the cleanest from experience as it reduces branch reintegration issues. Currently the project I'm working on has two public version support branches, with trunk representing the latest dev version.